# Cannot move Robotiq 2F-140 in ROS

Tags: ros, moveit, ros-kinetic, gripper

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a robot configuration with an UR10 robot and a Robotiq 2F-140 gripper in ROS and Gazebo and when I try to control the gripper to open or close it, it does not work. I am a new ROS user and maybe I am making a mistake when I declare the properties of the robot when using MoveIt Setup Assistant. Here I leave the terminal report:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/608a606c8b2755679e63af0c18ea0721

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

Edit: I know that the question may not be done good enough. So I am going to explain a little more my problem. I am trying to conect a simulation with MoveIt and Gazebo using a UR10 robot and a 2F-140 (2 fingers Robotiq Gripper). The point is that when I try to move it from MoveIt using the plannification tool of RVIZ, It comes to an ERROR. I've already made this tutorial:
http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html

And I see that the gripper fingers moves when you launch the demo.launch file. But when I try to do it with the UR10 robot and 2F-140 gripper, it does not work and I believe that I have made a proper config for the controllers. As it is written in the tutorial example, I have set up the controller in the following way:

```
 - name: hand_controller action_ns: gripper_cmd 

   gripper_cmd type: GripperCommand 

   default: true 
   joints: 
     - finger_joint
```

So, how can I launch that GripperCommand on a simulation with Gazebo and MoveIt in order to move the joints of the gripper propperly? I have to say that the UR10 robot moves itself without a problem.
Thanks for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/326387/cannot-move-robotiq-2f-140-in-ros/) by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 59 on 2019-06-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Reposting from the comments!

This [link will help you!](https://github.com/philwall3/UR5-with-Robotiq-Gripper-and-Kinect)

---

Originally posted by [pmuthu2s](https://answers.ros.org/users/33024/pmuthu2s/) with karma: 224 on 2019-06-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [drodgu](https://answers.ros.org/users/43205/drodgu/) on 2019-06-25**:
It helps. What I was doing wrong is not picking the good joint to improve the controller. I used a kinematic chain between the gripper_base_link and the left_inner_finger and the right part moves with mimic (repeat the gripper configuration in MoveIt Setup Assitant). Thank you very much for your help! SOLVED